# Show $\begin{bmatrix}d-\lambda\cr -c\end{bmatrix}$ is eigenvector of $\begin{bmatrix}a &b\cr c&d\end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

**Show $A=\begin{bmatrix}d-\lambda\cr -c\end{bmatrix}$ is eigenvector of $\begin{bmatrix}a &b\cr c&d\end{bmatrix}$**

I first did $\operatorname{det}(A-\lambda I)=0$ and got $\lambda^2+(-a-d)\lambda+(ad-bc)=0$

To that end, I then tried doing the quadratic formula but that really didn't get me anywhere. I need to somehow get $\lambda$ values to get the eigenvectors but I can't even get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{bmatrix}a &b\cr c&d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}d-\lambda\cr -c\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}ad-\lambda a-bc\\cd-\lambda c-cd\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda d-\lambda^2\\-\lambda c\end{bmatrix}=\lambda\begin{bmatrix}d-\lambda\\-c\end{bmatrix},$$ where the second equality follows using  $\lambda^2+(-a-d)\lambda+(ad-bc)=0$.

**Edit:** Of course since an eigenvector must be non-zero, therefore this is only true when $d \neq \lambda$ and/or $c\neq 0.$

Comment: An eigenvector is nonzero, by definition.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, edited.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're missing a very important assumption, namely that $\lambda$ is supposed to be an eigenvalue of the matrix. Then the rank of
$$
\begin{bmatrix} a-\lambda & b \\ c & d-\lambda \end{bmatrix}
$$
is at most one. If the second row of the matrix is not zero, then you get an eigenvector by solving the equation $cx+(d-\lambda)y=0$, because the vector $\left[\begin{smallmatrix} x\\y\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ surely satisfies also $(a-\lambda)x+by=0$. A nonzero solution is certainly
$$
\begin{bmatrix} d-\lambda \\ -c \end{bmatrix}
$$
However the statement is wrong, in general and the assumption that $d-\lambda\ne0$ or $c\ne0$ is *necessary*. Consider the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
Then the only eigenvalue is $1$ and the assigned vector is
$$
\begin{bmatrix} d-\lambda \\ -c \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 - 1 \\ -0 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
which is *not* an eigenvector.

Another instance where this fails is when $a=b=c=d=0$.